# How to smoothly change html <img> src on mouseover

Tags: angular, image, animation, angular-animations

I have 5 images that have to change one by one smoothly. When I'm hovering over it.
I mean how in angular show photos one by one. Changing src of img tag smoothly.
My ts

```js
    logoData = [
     "assets/img/logoState1.png",
     "assets/img/logoState2.png",
     "assets/img/logoState3.png",
     "assets/img/logoState4.png",
     "assets/img/logoState5.png",
    ];

    public imgSrc: any = this.logoData[0];

    Over() {
      this.logoData.forEach(
        (item, index) => {
          setInterval(() => {console.log(item); this.imgSrc = item}, (index+1) * 1000)        
        }
      )
    }
```

My HTML

```html
    <div class="logoContainer">
      <img class="img-fluid" [src]="imgSrc" (mouseover)="Over()" />
    </div>
```

Comment: Why don't add just a `transition` for the img?

Comment: and how exactly it's going to work?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you want a "crossfade" effect. It's two images on top of eachother, one fading in and one fading out. So you need to stack your images on top of eachother and fade the current one out while fading the next one in.

There's a lot of other nuances since the user is free to mouseover and mouseout halfway through animations.

Here's an implementation I think is pretty decent:

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-uxxd9e?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Make sure `BrowserAnimationsModule` is imported.

```js
...
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

@NgModule({
  imports: [..., BrowserAnimationsModule],
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

HTML

```html
<div (mouseover)="mouseover()" (mouseout)="mouseout()">
  <img
    *ngFor="let image of images"
    [src]="image.url"
    [@fade]="image.state"
    (@fade.done)="onDone($event)"
  />
</div>
```

CSS

```css
div {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 400px;
  width: 300px;
}

img {
  position: fixed;
  height: 400px;
  width: 300px;
}
```

Typescript

```js
import {
  animate,
  state,
  style,
  transition,
  trigger,
  AnimationEvent,
} from '@angular/animations';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

const fade = [
  trigger('fade', [
    state('show', style({ opacity: '1' })),
    state('hide', style({ opacity: '0' })),
    transition('show => hide', animate('1s')),
    transition('hide => show', animate('1s')),
  ]),
];

const SHOW = 'show';
const HIDE = 'hide';
const VOID = 'void';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  animations: fade,
})
export class AppComponent {
  images = [
    {
      url: 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1654076536803-3b55772a2ac0',
      state: SHOW,
    },
    {
      url: 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1654094736160-f9cff1c070a8',
      state: HIDE,
    },
    {
      url: 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1654111921656-72e847ec65b8',
      state: HIDE,
    },
    {
      url: 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1655070249064-2556803629b6',
      state: HIDE,
    },
    {
      url: 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1655282880891-9151896afab5',
      state: HIDE,
    },
  ];

  counter = 0;
  animating = false;
  stop = false;
  pauseTime = 1000; // time to show image before continuing animation (ms)

  get index() {
    return this.counter % this.images.length;
  }

  set index(value: number) {
    this.counter = value;
  }

  showNext() {
    if (this.stop) return (this.animating = false);
    this.images[this.index++].state = HIDE;
    this.images[this.index].state = SHOW;
  }

  mouseover() {
    this.stop = false;
    if (this.animating) return;
    this.animating = true;
    this.showNext();
  }

  mouseout() {
    // Signal to stop at the end of an animation cycle
    this.stop = true;
  }

  onDone(event: AnimationEvent) {
    // This fires once on init - do nothing
    if (event.fromState === VOID) return;
    if (event.toState === HIDE)
      setTimeout(() => this.showNext(), this.pauseTime);
  }
}
```